# Google Hangouts SMS Update not working for sms_body or Intent.EXTRA_TEXT

Tags: android

After yesterday's update to Google Hangouts (Dec 15, 2014), trying to pre-populate a body/message for an SMS is not working.

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
```

Anyone have a solution to fix this or will we have to wait for an update from Google?

Comment: This is fixed now with whatever update they pushed out. Verified in the Jan 9th, 2015 version.